# Opencv Android Eclipse speed worse on tutorial1 than tutorial 2 why ?????/

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, opencv

I would greatly appreciate help in understanding why the speed of response of the camera seems much better when executing opencv tutorial 2 for android then for opencv tutorial 1. I have setup the opencv environment in eclipse and lauch the tutorials on a motorola tablet.

I developed my own android application in eclipse and I found the speed the images were captured/displayed seemed much slower than what I saw when executing tutorial2. I also noticed that tutorial 1 was as slow as my application and was much slower executing than tutorial 2

I included my own application code in the tutorial 2 code and the speed was excellent. I renamed tutorial 2 and the application was still fast I renamed the packages and the speed deterioriated to what it was in my original android application. Does anyone know why ?
Thanks for looking at this. The tutorials are included with the samples in opencv.2.4.2-android-sdk.zip. I am using the opencv ready for use android library referred to in the documentation at http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html

Comment: Perhaps provide links to which tutorials you are referring to. I have lots of tutorials labelled tut1&2.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tutorial 0 & 1 are for the emulator which may mean they are using different implementations of the camera.

```
Running OpenCV Samples
"Also I want to note that only Tutorial 0 - Android Camera and Tutorial 1 - Add OpenCV samples are
able to run on Emulator from the Android SDK. Other samples are using OpenCV Native Camera which
does not work with emulator."
```

Afraid i haven't run the tutorials my self so not much help.